# Creating mountains

Tags: 3d, directx, directx-10

I am currently following Frank D. Luna's DirectX 10 book. I have just come across a method he uses for rendering mountains and I am not quite sure I understand why he uses it. For the vertex buffer he uses: (n and m are rows and columns and dx is 1.0f)(getHeight puts x and z into a function resembling a mountain)

```
float dx = 1.0f;
        float halfWidth = (n - 1)*dx*0.5f;
        float halfDepth = (m - 1)*dx*0.5f;
        for (DWORD i = 0; i < m; ++i)
        {
            float z = halfDepth - i*dx;
            for (DWORD j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            {
                float x = -halfWidth + j*dx;

                // Graph of this function looks like a mountain range.
                float y = getHeight(x, z);

                vertices[i*n + j].pos = D3DXVECTOR3(x, y, z);

                // Color the vertex based on its height.
                if (y < -10.0f)
                    vertices[i*n + j].color = BEACH_SAND;
                else if (y < 5.0f)
                    vertices[i*n + j].color = LIGHT_YELLOW_GREEN;
                else if (y < 12.0f)
                    vertices[i*n + j].color = DARK_YELLOW_GREEN;
                else if (y < 20.0f)
                    vertices[i*n + j].color = DARKBROWN;
                else
                    vertices[i*n + j].color = WHITE;
            }
        }
```

Then for the indices buffer he uses:

```
int k = 0;
        for (DWORD i = 0; i < m - 1; ++i)
        {
            for (DWORD j = 0; j < n - 1; ++j)
            {
                indexlist[k] = i*n + j;
                indexlist[k + 1] = i*n + j + 1;
                indexlist[k + 2] = (i + 1)*n + j;

                indexlist[k + 3] = (i + 1)*n + j;
                indexlist[k + 4] = i*n + j + 1;
                indexlist[k + 5] = (i + 1)*n + j + 1;

                k += 6; // next quad
            }
        }
```

If someone could explain these two buffer uses to me that would be great. I am just not quite sure why he uses these equations and what these equations do.

Comment: This is a simple regular grid. The calculations for the index buffer compute the three indices of a triangles' vertex within the buffer. What exactly don't you understand? Explaining every detail is a bit too much. Do you know how index buffers work in general?

Comment: I don't really understand why he uses i*n + j when he is selecting which vertices he wants in the vertex buffer. I do not need an explanation of the VB or IB but rather the numbers he uses inside of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the vertexbuffer, the term `i * n + j` is used to calculate the index of the current vertex. `j` is used for the position on the x-axis. So if you increment `j` and keep `i`, you'll get to the vertex to the right on the same row. The index is also increased by 1. If you increment `i` and keep `j`, you'll get to the vertex below the current one. The index is increased by `n` (the width of the field). This is natural, because the vertices in between have to be there.

Using a width of `n = 4`, you get the following numbering

```
\ j| 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  |
i \|    |    |    |    |
---+----+----+----+----+
 0 | 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  |
 1 | 4  | 5  | 6  | 7  |
 2 | 8  | 9  | 10 | 11 |
 ...
```

You see that moving from row `i` to row `i+1` results in the index being increased by the fields width, while going from column `j` to `j+1` results in the index increased by 1. This results in the formula `j + i * n`.

The same formula is used for the calculation of the index buffer.

The first triangle is:

```
col j    , row i     -> j + i * n
col j + 1, row i     -> j + 1 + i * n
col j    , row i + 1 -> j + (i + 1) * n
```